# W002<head> is missing X-UA-Compatible <meta> tag that disables old IE compatibility modes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap

This is my simple code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset='UTF-8'/>
 <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'/>
 <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'/>
 <title>Hello</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='jumbotron'>
   <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   <p>This is our first sample example that will be more awesome in the next chapters!</p>
   <a class='btn btn-primary btn-lg' href='#' role='button'>
    Bootstrap by Example, Chapter 1
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I check it by [Bootlint](http://www.bootlint.com/) and get the error:

> W002`<head>` is missing X-UA-Compatible `<meta>` tag that disables old IE compatibility modes

Hm... But my code has the X-UA-Compatible `<meta>` tag. Why does Bootlint tell me about it?

Comment: It's worth noting that this check will be dropped in the next Bootstrap and corresponding Bootlint version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct tag is with lowercase `e` in `edge`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Then it passes the Bootlint without problems.